# Is "connecting" used correctly in the sentence below?

Tags: modifiers

The *ed*-modifier and *ing*-modifier have been very difficult topics of English. Can I use both of them in the following sentence :

> There have been 2 bridges erected, **connecting** the lake’s shores.

I know it will be correct if I replace *connecting* by *to connect* but I really want to learn more about the *ed*- and *ing*- modifiers.

Comment: _Connecting_ here would be the equivalent of _which connect_.

Comment: Whereas the infinitive would be a purpose infinitive rather than a relative clause. However, in the case of a bridge, the purpose and the effect are identical, so the sentences are identical in meaning.

Comment: If you are asking whether it is grammatical to say "There have been 2 bridges erected, connected the lake’s shores," the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler comments, in the *specific* example given in the question, since the actual *purpose* of building bridges is to connect "shores", it makes no difference to the meaning whether you use ***connecting*** (simply describing what the bridges do) or ***to connect*** (a *purpose* infinitive, explaining *why* the bridges were built). But with syntactically similar alternatives, it *can* make a difference...

> 1: *He raised his voice, **frightening** the children* - he *might not have intended* to frighten them
> 2: *He raised his voice, **to frighten** the children* - he *definitely* intended to frighten them

---

EDIT:
There's some confusion about exactly what's being queried here, so I'll just add one more example...

> 3: *He raised his voice, [and] **frightened** the children* - same meaning as #1

...where omitting the conjunction ***and*** would be an *extremely* unlikely stylistic choice outside of "poetic" contexts, but essentially example #3 just combines the two simple statements *He raised his voice* and *He frightened the children* into one single "compound" sentence.

OR one could quite naturally use ***and that*** or just ***which*** instead of ***and***, to "causally" link the two assertions. This implies the children being frightened is a *consequence* of him raising his voice, but it says nothing about whether he *intended* that consequence.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of whether "connect**ed**" is correct.

Comment: I see nothing in the question to suggest that OP wants to know whether *There have been 2 bridges erected, **connected** the lake’s shores* would be a valid utterance. It's true he does say he wants "to learn more about the **ed-** and **ing-** modifiers", but quite frankly I consider that far too basic to address even here on ELL unless OP gives some more background as to why he doesn't understand standard verb inflections in English.

Comment: Yeah, you can't learn everything about -ed and -ing endings from that one sentence, so this question is probably off-topic for being too broad. As to my comment, I read the OP's first two sentences to mean they're directly asking whether that would be a valid utterance.

Comment: I've tried to address your point with an edit